# Update one field of one record in data collection using JavaScript immutability-helper or {...data, }

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I have data:

```
var data = [
    {field1: 'a', field2: 'aa', field3: 1},
    {field1: 'b', field2: 'bb', field3: 2},
    {field1: 'c', field2: 'cc', field3: 3},
    {field1: 'd', field2: 'dd', field3: 4},
]
```

And I am trying to use immutability-helper https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper or React `{...data, }` construction to arrive at the following result: I need to find row (one or more) with `field2` value `'cc'` and set its `field3` to `5`. What code can I use?

Comment: I corrected the example

Answer (score 2):

You can use plain JavaScript for this:

```
data.map(d => d.field2 === 'cc' ? ({...d, field3: 5}) : d);
```

To explain what's going on: This'll create a new array, where each element is a projection of an element in the original array. If it matches the condition, a copy of the object is created and modified based on your requirement. If it doesn't match, then it is placed in the array as-is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple javascript function [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var data = [{field1: 'a', field2: 'aa', field3: 1},{field1: 'b', field2: 'bb', field3: 2},{field1: 'c', field2: 'cc', field3: 3},{field1: 'd', field2: 'dd', field3: 4}];

/* Using ...o to create a copy of object and updating the value in copied object. */
var result = data.map(o => Object.assign({...o}, {field3 : o.field2 === 'cc'? 5 : o.field3}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript's [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this in an **immutable approach**:

```js
var data = [
    {field1: 'a', field2: 'aa', field3: 1},
    {field1: 'b', field2: 'bb', field3: 2},
    {field1: 'c', field2: 'cc', field3: 3},
    {field1: 'd', field2: 'dd', field3: 4},
]


var newData = data.reduce((accumulator, obj) => {
  return accumulator.concat((obj.field2 === 'cc' ? {...obj, field3: 5} : obj));
}, []);

console.log(newData);
```